# Fusible numbers -- can we prove fuse(4) is finite?

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics

[Fusible numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40404/proof-of-recursive-formula-for-fusible-numbers) have been discussed here before. Other links: [fusible numbers](http://www.mathpuzzle.com/fusible.pdf). [OEIS A188545](http://oeis.org/A188545). You have an unlimited number of irregularly burning fuses that will nevertheless burn for exactly 1 minute.  What is the smallest amount of time you can measure just over $0, 1, 2, 3, 4$ minutes?

The smallest fusible number above 0 is $0 + 2^{-1}$.
The smallest fusible number above 1 is $1 + 2^{-3}$.
The smallest fusible number above 2 is $2 + 2^{-10}$.
The smallest fusible number above 3 is $3 + 2^{-1541023937}$.

Let fuse(0) through fuse(3) be $1, 3, 10, 1541023937$. Actually, that last number is under some debate, there are some papers arguing that it is much larger.

After wrangling with this, I'm wondering if there is a clever proof that fuse(4) and beyond are finite numbers.

Comment: You just need to show that the fusible numbers are well-ordered.  This is demonstrated here: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1202.5614v1.pdf